GPTCache : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_ids'
Getting the below Error when using GPTCache with Postgres, AzureChatOpenAI, Faiss and LangChain.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 21
     19 cache_base = CacheBase(name='postgresql',type='postgresql', sql_url='postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/gptcache'),
     20 vector_base = VectorBase('faiss',dimension=langchain_embeddings.dimension)
---> 21 data_manager = get_data_manager(cache_base=cache_base, vector_base=vector_base,eviction_base=EvictionBase('memory', policy='lru', maxsize=10, clean_size=2, on_evict=lambda x: print(x)))
     22 llm_cache = Cache()
     23 llm_cache.init(
     24     pre_embedding_func=get_messages_last_content,
     25     embedding_func=langchain_embeddings.to_embeddings,
     26     data_manager=data_manager,
     27     similarity_evaluation=SearchDistanceEvaluation(),config=Config(log_time_func=log_time_func, similarity_threshold=0.9),    post_process_messages_func=temperature_softmax)

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/notebook-Bq_6nM4f/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gptcache/manager/factory.py:206, in get_data_manager(cache_base, vector_base, object_base, eviction_base, max_size, clean_size, eviction, data_path, get_data_container)
    204     eviction_base = EvictionBase(name=eviction_base)
    205 assert cache_base and vector_base
--> 206 return SSDataManager(cache_base, vector_base, object_base, eviction_base, max_size, clean_size, eviction)

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/notebook-Bq_6nM4f/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gptcache/manager/data_manager.py:247, in SSDataManager.__init__(self, s, v, o, e, max_size, clean_size, policy)
    243 self.eviction_base = e
    245 if not isinstance(self.eviction_base, NoOpEviction):
    246     # if eviction manager is no op redis, we don't need to put data into eviction base
--> 247     self.eviction_base.put(self.s.get_ids(deleted=False))

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_ids'

Sample code to simulate:
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from gptcache.embedding import LangChain
from gptcache.adapter.api import init_similar_cache
from gptcache.adapter.langchain_models import LangChainLLMs
from gptcache.manager import get_data_manager, VectorBase, CacheBase
import time
from typing import Dict, Any
from gptcache.manager.eviction import EvictionBase
from gptcache.similarity_evaluation import SearchDistanceEvaluation
from gptcache.config import Config
from gptcache.adapter.langchain_models import LangChainChat
from langchain.schema import HumanMessage
from gptcache.processor.pre import get_messages_last_content
from gptcache import Cache


llm = AzureChatOpenAI(deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
                        model_name=OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
                        azure_endpoint=AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
                        openai_api_version=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_VERSION,
                        temperature=0)
embeddings_model = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-mpnet-base-v2")

langchain_embeddings = LangChain(embeddings=embeddings_model,dimension=768)

def log_time_func(func_name, delta_time):
        print("func `{}` consume time: {:.2f}s".format(func_name, delta_time))

cache_base = CacheBase(name='postgresql',type='postgresql', sql_url='postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/gptcache'),
vector_base = VectorBase('faiss',dimension=langchain_embeddings.dimension)
data_manager = get_data_manager(cache_base=cache_base, vector_base=vector_base,eviction_base=EvictionBase('memory', policy='lru', maxsize=10, clean_size=2, on_evict=lambda x: print(x)))
llm_cache = Cache()
llm_cache.init(
    pre_embedding_func=get_messages_last_content,
    embedding_func=langchain_embeddings.to_embeddings,
    data_manager=data_manager,
    similarity_evaluation=SearchDistanceEvaluation(),config=Config(log_time_func=log_time_func, similarity_threshold=0.9),    post_process_messages_func=temperature_softmax)

before = time.time()
chat = LangChainChat(chat=llm,cache_obj=llm_cache)
answer = chat(
        messages=[
            HumanMessage(
                content="Translate this sentence from English to Hindi. I love programming."
            )
        ]
    )
print(answer)
print("Read through Time Spent =", time.time() - before)

Reference : https://gptcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootcamp/langchain/qa_generation.html
